# Q: Efficiently get the oldest value, most recent value and count per group in large table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to improve my query performance / or a more efficient query design to get the min, max and count per group in a mysql table.

My required output is:

```
+---------+----------+----------+-----+
|      id | f_amount | r_amount | cnt |
+---------+----------+----------+-----+
|       1 |     1000 |      200 |   3 |
|       2 |      300 |      300 |   1 |
|       3 |      450 |      600 |   2 |
+---------+----------+----------+-----+
```

where f_amount is the oldest amount, r_amount is the most recent amount and cnt is the number of transactions for that particular id.

My query [which gets the desired result but is extremely slow]. My table has close to 1 billion records and each id itself has thousands of transactions and all the data is in MySQL.

I am not able to implement the same using a Common Table Expression.

```
SELECT     x.fund_id AS id, 
           min_amt AS f_amount, 
           max_amt AS r_amount, 
           z.cnt 
FROM       ( 
                  SELECT fund_id, 
                         amount AS min_amt, 
                         dt 
                  FROM   trans
                  WHERE  dt = 
                         ( 
                                SELECT Min(dt) 
                                FROM   trans g 
                                WHERE  g.fund_id = trans.fund_id)) x 
INNER JOIN 
           ( 
                  SELECT fund_id, 
                         amount AS max_amt, 
                         dt 
                  FROM   trans
                  WHERE  dt = 
                         ( 
                                SELECT Max(dt) 
                                FROM   trans g 
                                WHERE  g.fund_id = trans.fund_id)) y 
INNER JOIN 
           ( 
                    SELECT   fund_id, 
                             Count(fund_id) AS cnt 
                    FROM     trans g 
                    GROUP BY 1) z 
where      x.fund_id = y.fund_id 
AND        x.fund_id = z.fund_id 
ORDER BY   x.fund_id;
```

Table creation and sample data insert:

```
CREATE TABLE trans (
  fund_id int,
  amount int,
  dt date);



insert into trans values(1,1000,'2019-02-01');
insert into trans values(1,500,'2019-02-02');
insert into trans values(1,200,'2019-02-03');
insert into trans values(2,300,'2019-02-15');
insert into trans values(3,450,'2019-02-17');
insert into trans values(3,600,'2019-02-20');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation to get the first and last dates.  Then join in the results you want:

```
select t.fund_id, tf.amount as first_amount, tl.amount as last_amount, t.cnt
from (select t.fund_id, min(dt) as min_dt, max(dt) as max_dt, count(*) as cnt
      from trans t
      group by t.fund_id
     ) t join
     trans tf
     on tf.fund_id = t.fund_id and tf.dt = min_dt join
     trans tl
     on tl.fund_id = t.fund_id and tl.dt = max_dt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=634c69b65c8ef25e18fc5aa030a3214d) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Looking to your code and your data  .. seems you need

```
SELECT fund_id, Max(amount) , min(amount), count(*)
FROM   trans
group by fund_id
```

Comment: No problem, Also `MAX(dt)`, `MIN(dt)` also should be edited to `MAX|MIN(amount)` by the way i now notice.